# How to subset one dataframe and make it equal to corresponding dataframes in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tidyr

I am doing a plant senescence study, and I have four different measuring dates. My first measurement (the data below) is the benchmark that I need to make the other three data sets equal to.

Basically, I rated leaves at different points in the growing season on how much visual senescence they were displaying. At the first measurement, most of them are 100% healthy, and only a few of them are dead. I need to subset out the ones that do not equal 100, and only use those leaves for my data analysis in later work.

Here is the first dataset:

```
flowering <- data.frame(plot = c(101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101),
                   plant=c(1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5),
                   leaf.number=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
                   score = c(100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             30,
                             80,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             75,
                             90,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             10,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             35,
                             0))
```

Subsetting the dataset:

```
flowering_subset <- subset(data, score == 100)
```

Now we have subsetted the data. I now want the leaves in 'flowering_data' to be used in the other datasets. Only these leaves should be used. It should be noted that the leaves were carefully marked, so they were the exact ones I took in later measurements.

Here's an example of my next dataset:

```
dough <- data.frame(plot = c(101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101,
                            101),
                   plant=c(1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           4,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5,
                           5),
                   leaf.number=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                                 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
                   score = c(100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             90,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             90,
                             100,
                             100,
                             90,
                             100,
                             100,
                             90,
                             80,
                             80,
                             80,
                             30,
                             80,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             80,
                             80,
                             75,
                             90,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             80,
                             80,
                             80,
                             80,
                             10,
                             0,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             100,
                             90,
                             90,
                             90,
                             90,
                             35,
                             0))
```

I thought dplyr or tidyr would work, but if there's another option, that would be great.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can first filter for the wanted leaves, then join the other datasets to the pre-filtered first dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

flowering %>%
  filter(score == 100) %>%
  inner_join(
    .,
    dough,
    by = c("plot", "plant", "leaf.number"),
    suffix = c("_flowering", "_dough")
  )

   plot plant leaf.number score_flowering score_dough
1   101     1           1             100         100
2   101     1           2             100         100
3   101     1           3             100         100
4   101     1           4             100          90
5   101     1           5             100         100
6   101     1           6             100         100
7   101     1           7             100         100
8   101     1           8             100          90
9   101     1           9             100         100
10  101     2           1             100         100
...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!